# Sort data in stored procedure with own preferred order

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm having a table with columns

```
[ID] AS bigint
[CompanyID] AS bigint
[Name] AS nvarchar(50)
[Position] AS nvarchar(15)
```

And the position is constant in combobox, the values are President, Vice President, Secretary and so on. I need to sort the data as 1st one is president second one is vice president......

Answer (score 0):

```
order by ID
```

perhaps?

Unless you have another data column which can be used to `order by` in your query. It sounds quite specific, so you need something in the data which you can use to order them by.

Comment: thank you,   i got a solution.                                                                    SELECT [ID], [LabourFederationID], [Name], [AdministrativeCapacity] 
FROM   [dbo].[APP_Member] 
WHERE  ([LabourFederationID] = 1 OR 1 IS NULL) 
ORDER BY
(CASE [AdministrativeCapacity]
 WHEN 'President'   THEN 1
    WHEN 'Vice-President'   THEN 2
    WHEN 'Secretary'   THEN 3
    WHEN 'Cashier' THEN 4
    WHEN 'Assistant Cashier'  THEN 5
    ELSE 100 END) ASC, [Name] ASC

Comment: Yes this will work but what happens when you add another entry? you need to change your code. You should add an 'OrderBy' column to your table so you can order on that.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. Use case when to achieve it.

```
Create table #Employee(
ID bigint,
Name nvarchar(50),
Position nvarchar(15)
)

insert into #Employee values (031,'AAA','Secretary')
insert into #Employee values(781,'ZZZ','Secretary')
insert into #Employee values(166,'PPP','President')
insert into #Employee values(561,'BBB','Vice President')
insert into #Employee values(441,'KKK','Secretary')
insert into #Employee values(124,'DDD','Secretary')
insert into #Employee values(100,'ZZZ','Vice President')

select *,CASE 
WHEN Position='President' THEN 1 
WHEN Position='Vice President' THEN 2 
WHEN Position='Secretary' THEN 3 
END  AS [PositionOrder] from #Employee
order by [PositionOrder]

drop table #Employee
```